# Springboot + Hibernate: Duplicate entry Exception while save entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, join, duplicates

i got 2 simple entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Base {

   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(
        name="user_emails",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="email_id")
   )
   private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();

   // getter setter
}
```

And Email (dont have any reference to User)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class Email extends Base {

    private String sender;

    private String receiver;
}
```

With the first mail everything is working 
but now I want to save a second email to the user with the following code (error is thrown). The problem is, that they are 2 mails at the "saveUser-line" and i think hibernate try to save the first one again and get the duplicate entry exceptions. How i have to do it? Important to know: there are other objects like user and all of them try to save emails (also not working).

```
    // Create Email object
    eMailRepository.save(email);


    if (user != null) {
        user.getEmails().add(email);
        userDatabaseRepository.save(user); // ERROR THROWN
    }
```

Here are the created entity table

[image]

Here are the problem sql:

```
Hibernate: insert into user_emails (user_id, email_id) values (?, ?)
```

And here the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseSeedConfig' defined in file [E:\Arbeit\---\target\classes\de\---\config\DatabaseSeedConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_1j6q2cqg40ooyo8m7kq2miws2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at de.dev.Pfffff.main(Pfffff.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_1j6q2cqg40ooyo8m7kq2miws2]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:296)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.save(Unknown Source)
    at de.dev.service.EMailQueueService.addEMailToQueue(EMailQueueService.java:132)
    at de.dev.service.EMailQueueService.addEMailToQueue(EMailQueueService.java:91)
    at de.dev.service.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:173)
    at de.dev.config.DatabaseSeedConfig.setUpAdminUser(DatabaseSeedConfig.java:133)
    at de.dev.config.DatabaseSeedConfig.afterPropertiesSet(DatabaseSeedConfig.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1340)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2486)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'UK_1j6q2cqg40ooyo8m7kq2miws2'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you share exception? Also turn on show_sql flag to see insert statements

Comment: Sure, i did it :)

Comment: Can you use Set instead of List for emails? You will avoid duplicates

Comment: then hibernates two PKs (user_id, email_id) in entity table so i cant add two entries (2 mails) for one user.

Comment: When you call addEmail for Set element won’t be added and you will avoid duplicates. Additional why are you using JoinTable instead of JoinColumn?

Comment: the problem is not the new added mail. the older one is the problem.
if i got User A with Email A attached. Everything is fine. Later.. i load the User A with the old Email A and add Email B. And if i save the User A now, he try to save Email A and got the duplicate error. He should skip this part.

Comment: Hm, did you try just to load user and save it, because if you are right then this will throw an exception

Comment: yes you are right, i test it and it happens ... dont know what i have to do ...

Comment: Can you share equals and hashcode methods?

Answer (score 0):

won't help you `userDatabaseRepository.saveOrUpdate(user);` instead of `userDatabaseRepository.save(user);` when you calling it for second time?

Comment: i dont have the methode "saveOrUpdate"

Comment: What interface your repositories extends?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

#### Email.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends Base {

   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(
        name="user_emails",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="email_id")
   )
   private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();

   private void addEmail(Email email){
      emails.add(email);
   }

   private void removeEmail(Email email){
      emails.remove(email);
   }
}
```

#### UserRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  User findByNameAndSurname(String name, String surname);

}
```

#### EmailRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface EmailRepository extends JpaRepository<Email, Long> {

   Email findBySenderAndReceiver(String sender, String receiver);

}
```

#### SomeClass.java

```java
@Autowired
private EmailRepository emailRepository;
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

/*
Some code
*/

emailRepository.saveAndFlush(email);

Email email = emailRepository.findBySenderAndReceiver("Sender", "Receiver");
emailRepository.flush();

User user = userRepository.findByNameAndSurname("Carlos", "Matos");

if(user != null){
 user.addEmail(email);
 userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
}
```

Comment: How does this even work if User#addEmail() is private ?